# My PS2 Mouse does not want to work on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

My PS2 Mouse does not want to work on Win 7. I reinstalled Windows 7 3 times and still my mouse does not want to work, PS2 keyboard works fine.

Windows boots up and then I can only use the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem by finally connecting to the net and then let windows search for device drivers automatically. Works

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by install it?

What is the model number / make and does it have weird functions?

I have never had a problem with bog standard PS2 Keyboard / mice and have never seen a problem with Windows with them:S

All I can really say is check the connection and if through driver you mean it is some weird wireless model with extra functions, try re syncing it with the base as the settings may have been lost.

Comment: PS2 Mouse is Gigabyte, everything works, I have 2 partitions Ubuntu and Windows 7 and Ubuntu the mouse works 100%

Comment: Could you have a look in device manager using the instructions here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager
and see if it has been disabled or is just not there.

Comment: There is a little yellow triangle with and exclamation mark.

Comment: When you double click on the device (with the yellow triangle) what does Windows report the error as? Also, what is the model of the mouse, I have never seen this before with a PS2 mouse and you have me interested!

Comment: Me neither, 

Mouse: Gigabyte
Model: GM-AP

Error: This device cannot start (Code 10)

Also it picks it up as a Microsoft PS2/Mouse

Comment: Wait, Gigabyte makes mice?

Answer (score 1):

Rule number one when trying to find the culprit:

- Try the product on another machine to rule out the product, or try an another similar product to rule out the machine.

(Posting the method for the second time today).

Comment: USB mouse works perfectly but PS2 mice don't work

Comment: It should be a "similar" product. Maybe the problem is with the PS/2 port, you cannot rule out a PS/2 mouse with a USB one.

Comment: The port is fine, since it works on Ubuntu, the PC is dual bootable, tried it with another Gigabyte PS/2 mouse and also no luck